# Beginner R Basics: Adding a Column

Tags: r

What is the step by step process to add a column to a dataset and save it as a new dataset?

I already have a dataset of average heights in inches. What I'm trying to do is add another column to the data set as centimeters. I've tried using both the mutate and to c to add a converted column to the dataset but for whatever reason I continue to recieve an error.

```
x<-heights$height
y<-x * 2.54
heights_cm<-mutate(x, y=cm)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `new_height <- mutate(heights, heights_cm = height * 2.54)`

Comment: When I attempt to do this is says: "Error in mutate(x, y = cm) : could not find function "mutate" how do I resolve that error?

Comment: `mutate` is from `dplyr` library, you need to load the library `dplyr` before running it with `library(dplyr)`. In base R, you can do : `new_height <- transform(heights, heights_cm = height * 2.54)`

Comment: AH! I forgot about transform.

Comment: You can also just use the R base : `new_heights <- heights; new_height$heights_cm <- new_heights$height * 2.54`

Comment: I used transfrom and renamed it like this, heights2<-new_height. Using heights2$sex=="Female" it returns T/F. Why is that, and how do I correctly use the filter function? Or and am I still using the incorrect library?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

```
heights_cm <- 2.54*(heights$height)
```

if you have this error : `non-numeric argument to binary operator`
check the class of using the command class and if it's not numeric use the command as.numeric